# Issue with trying to serialize object containing an attribute of type bytes

Tags: json, byte, avro, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have avro records which i am publishing to a pubsub topic of message encoding JSON type. The fields qty and cur is of type bytes in avro schema.
Subscription type is push to bq.

```
{'id': 1830170602, 'qty': b"'\x10", 'cur': b'J\xc4\xa0'}
```

The code reads the above avro data from a file and ingests into a topic.

```
reader = DataFileReader(open(file_name, "rb"), DatumReader())
for x in reader:
    # Get the topic encoding type.
    topic = publisher_client.get_topic(request={"topic": topic_path})
    encoding = topic.schema_settings.encoding

    # Encode the data according to the message serialization type.
    if encoding == Encoding.JSON:
        data_str = json.dumps(x)
        print(f"Preparing a JSON-encoded message:\n{data_str}")
        data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
```

Error failing at line 10 at json.dumps:

```
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Tried to change the topic message encoding to Binary. Not sure on how to solve this.
Should the byte field value be encoded with base64? (Asking based on reading about encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll have to encode the byte object provided in the AVRO file to base 64 object because byte objects cannot be serialized.

Sample AVRO input to be published to Pub/Sub topic:

{ "StringField": "ashu", "IntField": 10, "ByteField": base64.b64encode(b'J\xc4\xa0').decode('utf8')}

**Code:**

```
publisher_client = PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher_client.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)


#Python dictionary that matches the Avro schema

record= { "StringField": "ashu", "IntField": 10, "ByteField": base64.b64encode(b'J\xc4\xa0').decode('utf8')}


# Get the topic encoding type.
topic = publisher_client.get_topic(request={"topic": topic_path})
encoding = topic.schema_settings.encoding


if encoding == Encoding.JSON:
        data_str = json.dumps(record)
        print(f"Preparing a JSON-encoded message:\n{data_str}")
        data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
```

**Output:**

```
Preparing a JSON-encoded message:
{"StringField": "ashu", "IntField": 10, "ByteField": "SsSg"}
Published message ID: 6575130297315595
```